# HTML.LabelFor doesn't render properly

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, label, html.labelfor

I am trying to use Html.LabelFor like this but it doesn't render properly i.e instead of showing ProviderName value like "AT&T" its just displaying `ProviderName` text and not the value of `ProviderName`.

```
<div id="ServiceProvider" class="main_filter" name="filterDiv">
    <h4>Service Providers</h4>
    @for (var i = 0; i < allProviders.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="filter_chkbox_div">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => allProviders[i].Selected, new { value = allProviders[i].ProviderCode, id = allProviders[i].ProviderCode, style="display:none" })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => allProviders[i].ProviderName)
        </div>
    }
```

Whereas when I use Html.DisplayFor like this:

```
<label>@Html.DisplayFor(m => allProviders[i].ProviderName)</label>
```

it displays the value of ProviderName. Whats wrong with my code? I want to use Html.LabelFor. Please help

Comment: `LabelFor()` displays the property name (or the value of `DisplayAttribute.Name` if applied) - that's its purpose. In your case you can use `@Html.LabelFor(m => allProviders[i].ProviderName, allProviders[i].ProviderName)` to display the value of the property but associate the label with the checkbox (but as noted previously, your code will fail because of your incorrect use of `CheckBoxFor()`)

Comment: Ok. Actually I want to give a specific Ids to the `ProviderName`. Is it possible to give and id to DisplayFor()? Something like `<label>@Html.DisplayFor(m => allProviders[i].ProviderName, new { id = allProviders[i].ProviderCode })</label>`

Comment: What do you mean give `id`? `DisplayFor()` just generates some text. You cannot add attributes because it does not generate an element.

Comment: Start by removing `id = allProviders[i].ProviderCode` and the label will be associated with the checkbox.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer? Its not clear through your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `LabelFor()` is to display the name of the property (or if the property includes a `[Display]` attribute, then the value of its `Name` property), and to associate it with a form control (clicking on it will set focus to the control).

However there is are [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.String%29) that allows your specify the text to be displayed, so in your case it would be

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => allProviders[i].ProviderName, allProviders[i].ProviderName)
```

which will generate

```
<label for="allProviders_0__ProviderName">AT&T</label>
```

however this will not act as a label (to set focus) because you have overridden the `id` attribute of the associated control. Its not clear why your would do that (and if `ProviderCode` is not unique then you generating invalid html), but you should be removing `new { id = allProviders[i].ProviderCode }` from the `CheckBoxFor()` method so that the the default `id` attribute (`id="allProviders_0__ProviderName"`) is generated.

Side note: You use of `new { value = allProviders[i].ProviderCode }` means that model binding will fail (you should never set the value attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods). Your property `Selected` is typeof `bool` but `ProviderCode` is not. You are generating a value attribute which cannot be bound to a `bool` and the result will be that if the checkbox is checked it will submit (say) "ABC", binding will fail and the value will be set to `false`, and if its unchecked, the value will also be set to `false`.